# passing model from view to controller using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, jquery

I have a view

```
@using staffInfoDetails.Models
@model staffInfo

<link href="../../Content/myOwn.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{staffInfo stf = Model; 
  }

<div id="education1">
@using (Html.BeginForm("addNewEdu","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.StaffId)
    <table>    
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Board</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>PassedYear</th>
        <th>Division</th>
    </tr>     
    <tr> 
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.eduList)
    </tr>
    <tr>
    @*<td><input type="submit" value="create Another" id="addedu"/> </td>*@
    @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("Add New", "addNewEdu", new {  Model })</td>*@    
    </tr>
    </table>  
}
<button id="addedu">Add Another</button>
</div>
```

I want to pass the model staffInfo to controller using jquery as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addedu").live('click', function (e) {
//            e.preventDefault();           
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/addNewEdu",
                type: "Post",
                data: { model: stf },//pass model
                success: function (fk) {
                    //                    alert("value passed");
                    $("#education").html(fk);
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

the jquery seems to pass only elements not whole model so how can I pass model from the view to the controller so that I don't have to write the whole parameters list in jquery

Answer (score 5):

u can give ID to the form by using this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addNewEdu", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addNewEduForm" }))
{

}
```

Then in the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#addedu').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (form.valid()) { //if you use validation
        $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action'),
          type: form.attr('method'),
          data: $("#addNewEduForm").serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
                }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you trying to submit form with AJAX? Look at [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

```
$('#addedu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('form');

    if (form.valid()) { //if you use validation
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(r) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your values with `getElementById` then send your action:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "get", 
        url: "get_street_name", 
        data: { a: select },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Furthermore you can use JSON Why you have to pass model to controller just send your parameters with ajax then you can do any action in your controller method with using your models